# Delphi: Sending a keyboard code to a TEdit control

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events, delphi-5

Okay, I have an on-screen keypad made up of a panel with buttons with the kind of functionality you would expect 0 .. 9, Delete, BkSpace and Enter. It's an application for a touchscreen system.

The values entered by "pressing" the keys are shown in a `TEdit`.  Almost all of it works perfectly, but I have an issue with passing a keystroke to the `TEdit` control when I want to backspace within the `TEdit`.  I can simply delete the last character in the `TEdit` by using the Copy function and I guess I could do something similar for Delete.

But it would be much neater to pass the "key" button tag for backspace to the `TEdit` control and have it convert that to `VK_BACKSPACE` or `VK_DELETE`.

The problem is that while I've captured and used the virtual keycodes before, I've never tried to pass one to a control's event before and I can't find anything which really helps, either here or doing a general search or trawling through the Embarcadero documentation.

I'm sure this is dreadfully simple and I'm missing something easy, but could somebody point me at it, please?

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE THIS QUESTION - the answer WAS obvious.

Comment: in this case answer to your own question and accept it

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the SendMessage() method. Here is an example:

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=220